# Ruby Multi-Line Input for Only One Input

Tags: ruby, input

I have a small program that I'm working on that at one point I would like the user to be able to input a potentially multiline response.

I've found the example with

```
$/ = "END"
user_input = STDIN.gets
puts user_input
```

But this makes all inputs require the END keyword, which I would only need for the one input.

How can I produce a multi-line input for just the one input?

Comment: The user obviously needs a way to tell you when he or she is finished. That might be an escape key, for example, or two returns in a row.  You might consider using [IO#getc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-getc) for input.

Comment: The easiest way to signal "I'm finished" is with `Ctrl-D`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`IO#gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-gets) has an optional parameter that allows you to specify a separator.  Here's an example:

```
puts "Enter Response"
response = gets.chomp

puts "Enter a multi line response ending with a tab"
response = gets("\t\n").chomp
```

Output:

```
Enter Response
hello
Enter a multi line response ending with a tab
ok
how
is
this
```

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know about that. Maybe replace "Gets has..." with [IO#gets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-gets) has...".

Comment: Thanks Cary, included the link.

Comment: When I used this, it ran right over my next gets.       print "Multi-line response: "
response = gets("done").chomp

print "One line Response: "
oneLine = gets.chomp

Answer (score 2):

This method accepts text until the first empty line:

```
def multi_gets(all_text='')
  until (text = gets) == "\n"
    all_text << text
  end
  return all_text.chomp # you can remove the chomp if you'd like
end

puts 'Enter your text:'
p multi_gets
```

Output:

```
Enter your text:
abc
def

"abc\ndef"
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this:

```
in = STDIN.readline(sep="\t\n")
puts in
```

ends the input. For more info see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-readline